# salt cloud launching EC2 servers into wrong subnet

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

This is really weird. I'm launching some windows 2012 servers into EC2 using salt-cloud. And tho I'm using this profile:

```
ec2_private_win_app1:
    provider: company-nonpod-us-east-1
    image: ami-xxxxxx
    size: c4.large
    network_interfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: 0
    PrivateIpAddresses:
        - Primary: True
    #auto assign public ip (not EIP)
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: False
    SubnetId: subnet-A
    SecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxx
    #block_device_mappings:
    #   - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
    #     Ebs.VolumeSize: 120
    #     Ebs.VolumeType: gp2
    #   - DeviceName: /dev/sdf
    #     Ebs.VolumeSize: 100
    #     Ebs.VolumeType: gp2
    tag: {'Engagement': '2112254190125', 'Owner': 'Tim', 'Name': 'production'}
```

And giving this command:

```
salt-cloud -p ec2_private_win_app1 USAB00005
```

The resulting server ends up in this subnet in AWS:

```
Subnet ID: subnet-B
```

I'm using salt-cloud version: `salt-cloud 2016.9.0-410-gdedfd82`

On a server running: `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511`

Just what in the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It was a yaml formatting problem. I ran the yaml through an online yaml parser, and was able to correct the issue:

```
ec2_private_win_app1:
  provider: company-nonpod-us-east-1
  image: ami-xxxxx
  size: c4.large
  ssh_username: root
  network_interfaces:
     - DeviceIndex: 0
       SubnetId: subnet-xxxxxx
       PrivateIpAddresses:
         - Primary: True
   #auto assign public ip (not EIP)
   AssociatePublicIpAddress: False
   SecurityGroupId:
     - sg-xxxxxx
```

Basically, I had to group the Subnet ID in the network_interfaces section in order for the servers to appear in the correct subnet.